# Android: Rearrange Buttons When Dynamically Adding Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

My question is better explained with a diagram, but here is the general idea:

I am dynamically adding buttons to the layout. The buttons are added throughout user interaction. If there is one button, I would like it to be centered in the parent.

```
|...............[Button 1]...............|
```

For two buttons, I would like them to be next to each other centered.

```
|..........[Button 1][Button 2]..........|
```

This pattern will continue until a certain amount of buttons (so as to not cluster them all on the same row/line). So let's say the maximum number of buttons per row/line is 4. So for any number of buttons greater than 4, I would like them to be split evenly on the following rows/lines. So for 5 buttons it would look something like this:

```
|.....[Button 1][Button 2][Button 3].....|
|..........[Button 4][Button 5]..........|
```

Basically I would like to be able to programmatically layout the buttons in the rows/lines so each line contains the same (or as close to the same) number of buttons as possible, so they are distributed evenly.

---

Currently I have the buttons laid out in a grid format and are invisible until called, but it looks ugly. So it would look something like this:

```
|[Button 1][Button 2]....................|
```

Or if there were 5 buttons it would look like this:

```
|[Button 1][Button 2][Button 3][Button 4]|
|[Button 5]..............................|
```

This just looks ugly/tacky, so I would want them to be programmatically laid out like I explained in the top section.

---

Is it possible to do what I am asking? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

1/ Use a `RelativeLayout` as the root `ViewGroup` for all of this.

2/ Use a `LinearLayout` for each row of `Buttons`, set this to have unique Ids and to have `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` set to `WRAP_CONTENT` for its width and height. Use `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` as a rule, and for when you add a row (2nd, 3rd, 4th etc, i.e. not the 1st) additionally add the rule `BELOW`, and use the id of the row it should be below.

3/ To determine if a `Button` will fit inside a row, get the width of the row and of the `RelativeLayout` (in step 1) using `getMeasuredWidth()`. Using those you can check if the `Button` will fit - assuming they use fixed widths.

EDIT

Example (which doesn't include step 3):

In your Activity add a member variable `ViewGroup list`, then in Activity.onCreate():

```
list = new RelativeLayout(this);
list.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(list);
```

Add a method to add a button.

```
private void addButton(String btnTitle)
{
    // find out how many rows we have in our relative layout  
    int rowCount = list.getChildCount();

    int buttonCount = MY_MAX_BUTTONS_PER_ROW;

    // find out how many buttons are in the last row
    if (rowCount > 0) buttonCount = ((ViewGroup)list.getChildAt(rowCount-1)).getChildCount();

    final ViewGroup row;

    // do we have no rows, or is there no room for another button?
    if (rowCount == 0 || buttonCount >= MY_MAX_BUTTONS_PER_ROW)
    {
        // create a row 
        LinearLayout newRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        newRow.setId(rowCount+1);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rowLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        rowLP.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        if (rowCount > 0) rowLP.addRule(BELOW, rowCount);

        list.addView(newRow, rowLP);

        rowCount++;  

        row = newRow;
    }
    // .. there's room, so add it to the last row
    else 
    {
        row = (ViewGroup)list.getChildAt(rowCount-1);
    }

    // create one of your buttons
    // ...

    button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: The buttons are not fixed width, but they will all show up as the same size because of the length of text going in each one. Also, could you elaborate/explain more in your second step? I got confused and did not follow in the second part of step 2. Could you provide some sample code to demonstrate? Also, will your method handle my third example in the top section?